# Python-Guessing a number-High and Low

Tags: python

For my assignment I had to create a program where the user chose a number between 0-511 and my program had to guess it within 10 tries. 
An error came up telling me I had to define "response" but not sure exactly what to write. 
If anyone has any other advice to fix my code, that would be great. I am completely new to programming and any pieces of advice would help greatly!

Here is my code:

```
LOW = 0
HIGH = 511
guess = (LOW + HIGH)/2
response = 
print("Think of an integer from", LOW, "to", HIGH)

while not(response == "y" ):   
        response = input
        print("Is the answer", guess, "?")

        if (response == "L"):
              LOW = guess
              guess = (LOW + HIGH)/2

        elif (response == "y" ):

              high = into(guess)<br>
              guess = int(low + high)/2
              HIGH = guess

print("Is the answer", guess, "?")
response = input()
response("got it")
```

Comment: Please try to fix your indentation so it looks the same as it does in your text editor, sometimes it gets messed up when trying to copy it into SO.

Comment: I believe that `response = input` should be `response = input()` and the last line should be `print("got it")`.

Answer (score 1):

In general "help me do my homework" will not be answered here - see https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

However, I think you might find the following enlightening - often these we know how to do these sorts of tasks ourselves, and (especially for a student) have trouble breaking down the steps. I suggest the following:

Find a friend, and do the procedure with him. I see from your code that you know the rough procedure. Just do it yourself - keep numbers on paper if you need to. Don't concentrate on HOW you're doing it, don't analyse it. Just do it. Then do it again, writing down the steps you took - don't use loops at this stage, and don't generalize it yet, just note it down - if you have an audio recorder, say the steps out loud, so you can concentrate on what you're doing practically, not the underlying code. Write it down, break it down into steps, look at what you've done, roll up the loops. Then write the code.

Answer (score 0):

Anything other than `"y"` should work for `response`. I suggest setting it to none: `response = None`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html for info about `None`.